# Cleaner looking TCL GUI TK Button

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a Tk::Button that has a folder image on it. On some occasions we disable this button and the button image is kind of grayed out.

Example: [image]
[image]

Is there anyway to clean up the disabled look? Possible bind a separate image to use when disabled?

```
set ::FileSelect::folder_image [image create photo -file "$::env(Path)/include/images/folder.gif"]
set ::FileSelect::folder_image_disabled [image create photo -file "$::env(Path)/include/images/folder_disabled.gif"]
ttk::button $widget_name.browse -image { $::FileSelect::folder_image disabled $::FileSelect::folder_image_disabled }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the bitmap in whatever code sets the state to the disabled state.

For example:

```
if [should_be_disabled] {
    button configure -state disabled -image $disabled_image
} else {
    button configure -state normal -image $normal_image
```

If you are using themed widgets you can specify different images for each state. For example, to use the image `disabled_image` for the disabled state and `default_image` for the normal state you would do something like this:

```
ttk::button .b1 -image {default_image disabled disabled_image}
```

For more information on the themed button see [the man page for ttk::button](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_button.htm).

Comment: I am using ttk::buttons and I was attempting to do basically what you suggested but was struggling some. Would I then create two images, default_image and disabled_image and supply them like you do? I will give it another shot, maybe I was just doing something weird.

Comment: I must be missing something here, I added some example code above in the question. When I try and run it it tells me that 'image "$::FileSelect::folder_image" doesn't exist'.

Comment: @Tarmon: what do you know about curly braces? When you do `-image {$::FileSelect...}` it's probably not doing what you think it's doing. To answer your earlier question, yes, you need to create two separate images.

Comment: Wow I am amazing, still new to TCL so that slipped by me. Thanks for your help.